# How to generate many of the same form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Product` Model with the below table which has a `ProductsController` and **Form**:

```
    class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def self.up
        create_table :products do |t|
          t.string  :name
          t.decimal :price
          t.string :location

    end
```

How can i generate `name` and `price` again six times on my form to make six products ( six is a number i just threw out there) in the database?

**EDIT: Added the `:location` to give more of an explanation of what I'm trying to do.**

Only on one form Users can create products and can have as many products as they choose ( `:name` & `:price`) to be made and all have the same `:location` when they submit the form. This is basically a way to do [Nested Models](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) but with one table only ( including the Railscast Ajax, i will put this in myself).

Comment: You might need to clarify what you're asking.  It's not very clear.  Can you give a pseudo code example?  Do you mean in the template, or in your migration?

Comment: @dd1wtq Added more, if you need more feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has support for input arrays. Things like products[] can be submitted to the controller

Otherwise, you'd run into issues submitting a form with inputs with the same name and ID. You could bundle all the inputs up into a Javascript array and submit that via POST.

If you're using jQuery, you could name all your product name inputs like this:

```
<input class="product_name" type="text">
<input class="product_name" type="text">
<input class="product_name" type="text">
```

do something like

```
var products_array = [];
$(".products").each(function() {
  products_array.push($(this).val());
});
```

Out of curiosity, why do you want to enter multiple product on one page? Is this like an invoice type thing?

Comment: Users can create Products and its a hassle inputting one product at a time and having to create, go back to the page and start over again however amount of times the user needs to.

Comment: How many Jquery would i exactly need to know in order to do this? i have very little experience with Jquery as of now. What you wrote kind of makes sense to me.

Comment: added more for more clarification

Comment: In a high level view, I'd create some JS that adds new fields on the fly. (use jQuery or Prototype, whatever you feel more comfortable with). Make sure their name attribute specifies an array: `<input type="text" name="product_name[]>` Then in your controller, use Ruby's each() method to submit each item to the database.